# Calling C function with struct in C# - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, c, struct, pinvoke

I thought this one was fairly straight forward but still trying to understand all of this and having some issues.

I don't know much about the C function b/c i've been given limited information.

Here is the function call in C:

```
int GetCard(CardInfo card);
```

Here is the request structure:

```
typedef struct _tCardInfo
{
    char CardNumber[80];
    char isExist;

} TCardInfo, *pTCardInfo;
```

I want to pass the card number to see if it exists.

So in C# I did the following:

```
public struct CardInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string cardNumber;

    public byte isExist;
}

[DllImport("card.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetCardInfo(ref CardInfo cardInfo);
```

Then in the c# method:

```
CardInfo cardInfo = new CardInfo();

cardInfo.cardNumber = "1234567890"; 

int success = GetCardInfo (ref cardInfo);
```

The good thing about the DLL that I'm calling is it generates a log file. 
When I execute the call, the log tells me that I'm hitting the DLL but it is not passing the card number which then sets a message saying the card number was not passed.

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Is the C DLL expecting 8 bit chars (c# byte) or 16-bit unicode chars (C# char)?

Comment: Indeed, you're passing TCHARs to a function that demands chars.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're requesting TChar marshaling, but the DLL requires 8-byte characters. Change the C struct to wchar_t.

Also, use Visual Studio to set a breakpoint in your DLL, and actually inspect the data when it comes in! Visual Studio can debug across .NET/native boundaries, which is super cool!

Comment: Well, changing C# to ANSI may be the only option, but this is essentially it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add attribute StructLayout for struct

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CardInfo
{
...
```

Comment: I tried this too and it didn't work. 
I'm stumped as why the return value gives me nothing passed in and nothing passed out.

Comment: Changes nothing. That's the default!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the .Net struct like this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CardInfo
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr, SizeConst = 80)]
        public string cardNumber;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public sbyte isExist;
    }
```

And for the function declaration: try not to use the `CallingConvention` and `CharSet` in the DLL import, and use the `[In, Out]` attributes before the parameter.  Like this:

```
[DllImport("card.dll")]
public static extern int GetCardInfo([In, Out] CardInfo cardInfo);
```

Comment: Oops. I forgot the "Info" beside the "GetCard".
In c# I use ref because I pass in the card number and should get back a value in IsExist.
Unfortunately I am doing the c# code.  The other information is all i get from the DLL and nothing else.  that's why i stuck.